# Alert() javascript function not working in php

Tags: javascript, php

I know this is frequently asked question however I have tried using :

1. `script language='javascript'`
2. placed header in else after alert
3. `script type='text/javascript'`

Still I don't get alert box, while else parts executes perfectly.

Here's my code:

```
  <?php

 /* header('Content-Type: application/json');
 $response = array(); */
 if (isset($_GET['sid'])){

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "kaemiphk_greivance");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

$checkdata=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM officer_master WHERE pf_no = '".$_GET['sid']."'");
$query_data=mysqli_num_rows($checkdata);
if ($query_data == 0) {

//echo alert "welcome";
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js">';
    echo "alert('PF No. Does not exist. Please Contact Admin!!!');";
    echo '</script>';

 }
 else{
      header('Content-Type: application/json');
      $response = array();
      $select="SELECT m.officer_name,m.email,m.department,m.mobile_no,m.designation,n.quarter_no,n.address,n.colony,n.blueprint_quarter,n.type_of_quarter, n.area FROM officer_master m, quarter_master n WHERE n.pf_no='".$_GET['sid']."' AND m.pf_no = n.pf_no";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $select);  //mysql_query($qry);
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
array_push($response, $row);
}
}
echo json_encode($response);  
} 

 ?>
```

What am I missing here.
Thanks

Comment: Please share the possible errors in your browser console. Maybe they know something usefull :)

Comment: A script tag can either have a src attribute, or contain source, but not both. You need a separate script tag.

Answer (score 1):

You have your js files mixed up.
Include jquery and then your script, inside separate tags:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" ></script>';
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo "alert('PF No. Does not exist. Please Contact Admin!!!');";
echo '</script>';
```

By the way, you do NOT need jquery for a simple alert, as it is plain javascript. Try to avoid including external library if not needed, you will end up with a bloated code.
And printing js with php it's a bit of a hack. Why not just print it into your html or js file?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript inside a script tag that has an src attribute does not get executed, you have to create a second script tag after the jquery one.

```
<?php

/* header('Content-Type: application/json');
$response = array(); */
if (isset($_GET['sid'])){

   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "kaemiphk_greivance");

   if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

   $checkdata=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM officer_master WHERE pf_no = '".$_GET['sid']."'");

   $query_data = mysqli_num_rows($checkdata);
   if ($query_data == 0) {
//echo alert "welcome";
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js">';
    echo '</script>';
    echo "<script>alert('PF No. Does not exist. Please Contact Admin!!!');</script>";
   } else {
      header('Content-Type: application/json');
      $response = array();
      $select="SELECT m.officer_name,m.email,m.department,m.mobile_no,m.designation,n.quarter_no,n.address,n.colony,n.blueprint_quarter,n.type_of_quarter, n.area FROM officer_master m, quarter_master n WHERE n.pf_no='".$_GET['sid']."' AND m.pf_no = n.pf_no";
      $result = mysqli_query($con, $select);  //mysql_query($qry);
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        array_push($response, $row);
      }
    }
  echo json_encode($response);  
  } 
}
 ?>
```